# Automatic line breaking in minted

Tags: line-breaking, minted

I'm using the [`minted`](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) package to generate syntax-highlighted code snippets. The listing I want to show has some lines that overflow, though. Minted can automatically handle line breaks with the `breakline` option. But I want the line breaks to appear on the same level of indentation as the actual line.

I thought the `breakautoindent` option would do exactly what I wanted, but it doesn't indent the line break, no matter what the indent of the line is. The following code

```
\begin{minted}[linenos, breaklines, breakautoindent=true]{AMPL}
param n;  # Number of nodes in network

set NODES := 1..n;
set LINKS within (NODES cross NODES);

param Capacities {LINKS} >= 0;  # Maximum capacity for each edge


var Flow {(i, j) in LINKS} >= 0, <= Capacities[i,j];  
                            # Restrain the domain of the variables to [0, capacity]

maximize MaxFlow:  # Objective function (flow recieved by end node)
    sum {(i, n) in LINKS} Flow[i, n];



subject to Conservation:  # Ensure no flow is lost from start to end
    sum {(1, j) in LINKS} Flow[1, j] = sum {(i, n) in LINKS} Flow[i, n];

subject to Balance {k in (NODES diff {1, n})}:  # Transit nodes
    sum {(k, j) in LINKS} Flow[k,j]  == sum {(i, k) in LINKS} Flow[i, k];
\end{minted}
```

produces

[image: Output]

Notice that the line breaks have all the same level of indentation (i.e. none), but there are some lines that have a much higher indentation (e.g. the `# Restrain [...]` comment).

What is the source of the problem?

**Edit:** I've also tried `obeytabs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update for 2022/12/01**

`breakautoindent` is actually handled within `minted` by `fvextra`. The latest version of `fvextra` (v1.5 from 2022/11/30) automatically checks the first Pygments token on each line for leading whitespace, so `breakautoindent` should now give the expected output in essentially all cases regardless of how the Pygments lexer handles whitespace.

---

The [Pygments AMPL lexer](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/src/7941677dc77d4f2bf0bbd6140ade85a9454b8b80/pygments/lexers/ampl.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) treats whitespace as [Pygments `Text.Whitespace` tokens](http://pygments.org/docs/tokens/), which are "for specially highlighted whitespace".  As a result, indentation appears not as plain indentation characters (which is what `minted`'s `breaklines` works with), but rather as those characters wrapped in a Pygments token macro (in this case, `\PYG{+w}{<whitespace_chars>}`).

The easiest solution is to edit `ampl.py` to replace `(r'\s+', Text.Whitespace)` with `(r'\s+', Text)`.  It would technically be possible for `minted` to look for whitespace at the start of the first token in each line, but implementing that correctly (particularly if the token type needs to be taken into account) might be complicated.