# How to set width of indentation with breaklines when using minted?

Tags: pdftex, minted

I'm trying to solve a problem that seems to be identical to [Automatic line breaking in minted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453164/automatic-line-breaking-in-minted) (though that question title is less specific)... the issue is pertaining to the "wrapped" (or 'broken'? text, the text which is continued on subsequent lines) text, trying to get that appropriately indented to match the line it came from.

This picture shows the wrapped/broken lines which I want to be indented to the depth shown:
[image]

The solution in that other question seems to recommend hacking the pygments library which minted uses... !

Is there a solution more *appropriate* than hacking the pygments library?

My code:

```tex
\documentclass[varwidth=20cm,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{solarized-light}
\usepackage [T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{\sffamily
  \textcolor[rgb]{0.5,0.5,1.0}{\Large
  \oldstylenums{\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{LARGE}
  \inputminted[xleftmargin=5pt,breaklines,autogobble]{yaml}{kitchen_design.yaml}
\end{LARGE}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One particular unexplained challenge with the solution from the other question (hack the Pygments library) is: where to place the modified file? I can see Pygments installed via `pip3` and various python programs which rely on it... but given package management in Linux I see no reason to assume that `pdflatex` is even using that version of pyments and not a different one stored somewhere else.

Comment: The `pygmentize` that comes first in the default PATH will be used. What you want seems quite difficult: you want to take care of how many initial spaces are in a line, which is not currently done.

Comment: my line of thinking: `vim` can do this, why not `latex`?

Comment: Somebody found such a feature useful for `vim` and *programmed* it. You're apparently the first to ask for this feature, so somebody has to program Pygments to do it.

Comment: I understand the behavior needs to be programmed... I'm surprised that hasn't been done already though, as what I'm describing seems to me like obviously desirable behavior... like what about `autogobble`?  I found that in http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf but haven't been able to get that option or any others that appear to be associated with `breaklines` to have any visible effect.

Comment: ...so I'm not sure if it's because "I'm doing it wrong" or if it's because of something like "Pygments doesn't utilize Minted's featureset properly"